# Flickering when appending row to table JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read all the other articles and none seem to have helped.
The page in question is www.projectwhisper.net78.net

When the button is clicked, a row is added. 
But if you look carefully, there is a flicker near the bottom of the table.

Here is the HTML of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Hi There!</p><button id="the_button">Click to add row</button>
    <table id="content"><tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $("#the_button").click(function() 
       {
          var row=$("<tr><td>This is a row</td></tr>");
          row.hide()
          row.prependTo('table > tbody');
          row.slideDown(500);
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: Look at what flicker? You didn't provide a fiddle!

Comment: Generally it is preferred that when you ask a question and want to demonstrate code - you upload it to an isolated test environment like jsfiddle.net , codepen.io , jsbin.com or others rather than post a link to your site. It makes helping you much easier.

Comment: I suggest a newer version of jQuery (if you must use it) and using divs instead of table elements as such: http://jsfiddle.net/2gz8e/

Comment: jQuery 1.3 was released in 2009. _Why are you still using it?_

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/ZWVYz/)**

Try this

```
$("#the_button").click(function () {
    var row = $("<tr><td>This is a row</td></tr>");
    row.prependTo('table > tbody').hide();
    row.show(500);
   });
```

Each time the `row` is added to the top of the `table tbody` as a stack, since each element is prepended to the `table tbody`